# How to replace multiple variables in one line using Stata

Tags: stata, data-cleaning

I have some hand corrections to do in a data set and I wanted to do avoid repeating the `if` condition. For instance, instead of

```
sysuse auto, clear
replace mpg=21 if make=="AMC Concord"
replace rep78=4 if make=="AMC Concord"
replace mpg=23 if make=="AMC Pacer"
replace rep78=4.5 if make=="AMC Pacer"
```

the following code would be more parsimonious but it doesn't work

```
sysuse auto, clear
replace mpg=21 & rep78=4 if make=="AMC Concord"
replace mpg=23 & rep78=5 if make=="AMC Pacer"
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; that code would be more concise. It just is not legal Stata and nothing in the syntax diagram for `replace` suggests otherwise.

I can imagine some very contrived ways of re-writing the same code in fewer lines, while using `if`, but none would be, in my view, more attractive or easier to understand.

Looking up the observation number and using `in` rather than `if` would also shorten the code, but be less clear and highly fragile to changes in `sort` order.

Comment: Thanks. Right using `in` rather that `if` is not a good solution. Expanding the possibilities of `replace` would be a possible improvement!

Comment: You could suggest that. I don't think it would ever fly with StataCorp or even experienced users. Speaking for myself, I would argue against it.`replace` manifestly changes the data and making the syntax more complicated could have many downsides. You could always write your own program to accept multiple `replace` calls (this is a forum for programmers, after all).

Comment: Could we do it in R instead, and then refeed the data frame to Stata?

Comment: @GiuseppeBiondi-Zoccai OP wants to reduce 4 lines to 2 and shunting results back and forth between R and Stata will do better? I don't think so. In general, you are right, that one language will be more concise than another for certain things.

Comment: Thanks Guiseppe. I will use R here because I want to reduce 2*n lines to n (not only 4 lines to 2...).

Comment: Presumably your real problem is not with the auto dataset. There might be more structure in your real problem that would permit more concise code. But if it's a series of arbitrary `replace`s I don't have another answer. I am genuinely curious at how the R code will be much shorter.